# how to check time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm making a search page of a sport (badminton) where each team plays: morning, afternoon, evening.  There can be three play times in a week.  So the table is like this:

```
start_time = "08:00:00"
start_time2 = "12:00:00"
start_time 3 = "18:00:00"
```

or if the team only plays once a week, the table is like this:

```
start_time = "08:00:00"
start_time2 = "00:00:00"
start_time3 = "00:00:00"
```

Right now my query is like this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['time'])){
foreach ($time as $value){ //make day stay checked 2012/12/31
    if ($value == "早上") $morning = "checked";
    if ($value == "下午") $afternoon = "checked";
    if ($value == "晚上") $evening = "checked";   
}
if ($morning == "checked" and $afternoon != "checked" and $evening != "checked"){ //only morning
    $criteria .= "and (start_time < '12:00:00' or start_time2 < '12:00:00' or start_time3 < '12:00:00')";
}elseif ($morning == "checked" and $afternoon == "checked" and $evening != "checked"){ //morning + afternoon
    $criteria .= "and (start_time < '18:00:00' or start_time2 < '18:00:00' or start_time3 < '18:00:00')";
}elseif ($morning == "checked" and $afternoon != "checked" and $evening == "checked"){ //morning + evening
    $criteria .= "and ((start_time < '12:00:00' and start_time >= '18:00:00') or (start_tim2e < '12:00:00' and start_time2 >= '18:00:00') or (start_time3 < '12:00:00' and start_time3 >= '18:00:00'))";
}elseif ($morning != "checked" and $afternoon == "checked" and $evening != "checked"){ //afternoon
    $criteria .= "and ((start_time >= '12:00:00' and start_time < '18:00:00') or (start_time2 >= '12:00:00' and start_time2 < '18:00:00') or (start_time3 >= '12:00:00' and start_time3 < '18:00:00'))";
}elseif ($morning != "checked" and $afternoon == "checked" and $evening == "checked"){ //afternoon + evening
    $criteria .= "and (start_time >= '12:00:00' or start_time2 >= '12:00:00' or start_time3 >= '12:00:00')"; 
}elseif ($morning != "checked" and $afternoon != "checked" and $evening == "checked"){ //only evening
    $criteria .= "and (start_time >= '18:00:00' or start_time2 >= '18:00:00' or start_time3 >= '18:00:00')";
}
```

There are two problems:

1. Is there a better way to write less code so it runs faster?
2. How can I avoid checking if the start_time is 00:00:00?  Because if I don't skip the check, the condition will be true if I only want to search the morning.  Because morning is time less than 12:00:00, and 00:00:00 is less than 12:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing `if ($value == "早上") $morning = "checked";`? Simply use value to change the query.

```
 if ($value == "早上"){
        $criteria .= "and (start_time < '12:00:00' or start_time2 < '12:00:00' or start_time3 < '12:00:00')";
    }
  elseif ($value == "下午"){
       $criteria .= "and (start_time < '18:00:00' or start_time2 < '18:00:00' or start_time3 < '18:00:00')";  
    }
    elseif ($value == "value3"){
       $criteria .= "query3";  
    }
```

You can replace 'if' with 'switch' case if u want

```
switch ($value) {
    case 0:
        $criteria .= "query1" 
        break;
    case 1:
         $criteria .= "query2" 
        break;
    case 2:
         $criteria .= "query3" 
        break;
}
```